# Using gsl::zstring_view with C APIs

Tags: c++, string-view, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library, string-span

I'm trying to use modern string-handling approaches (like [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) or [GSL's `string_span`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/66809c6852a0250243db893ab5460bfdace063c4/include/gsl/string_span)) to interact with a C API (DBus) that takes strings as null-terminated `const char*`s, e.g.

```
DBusMessage* dbus_message_new_method_call(
    const char* destination,
    const char* path,
    const char* iface,
    const char* method 
    )
```

`string_view` and `string_span` don't guarantee that their contents are null-terminated - since spans are `(char* start, ptrdiff_t length)` pairs, that's largely the point. But GSL also provides a `zstring_view`, which *is* guaranteed to be null-terminated. The [comments](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/66809c6852a0250243db893ab5460bfdace063c4/include/gsl/string_span#L389-L390) around `zstring_span` suggest that it's designed exactly for working with legacy and C APIs, but I ran into several sticking points as soon as I started using it:

1. Representing a string literal as a `string_span` is trivial:

   ```
   cstring_span<> bar = "easy peasy";
   ```

   but representing one as a `zstring_span` requires you to wrap the literal in a helper function:

   ```
   czstring_span<> foo = ensure_z("odd");
   ```

   This makes declarations noisier, and it also seems odd that a literal (which is guaranteed to be null-terminated) isn't implicitly convertible to a `zstring_span`. `ensure_z()` also isn't `constexpr`, unlike constructors and conversions for `string_span`.
2. There's a similar oddity with `std::string`, which is implicitly convertible to `string_span`, but not `zstring_span`, even though `std::string::data()` has been guaranteed to return a null-terminated sequence since C++11. Again, you have to call `ensure_z()`:

   ```
   zstring_span<> to_zspan(std::string& s) { return ensure_z(s); }
   ```
3. There seems to be some const-correctness issues. The above works, but

   ```
   czstring_span<> to_czspan(const std::string& s) { return ensure_z(s); }
   ```

   fails to compile, with errors about being unable to convert from `span<char, ...>` to `span<const char, ...>`
4. This is a smaller point than the others, but the member function that returns a `char*` (which you would feed to a C API like DBus) is called `assume_z()`. What's being *assumed* when the constructor of `zstring_span` [expects a null-terminated range](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/66809c6852a0250243db893ab5460bfdace063c4/include/gsl/string_span#L406-L410)?

If `zstring_span` is designed "to convert zero-terminated spans to legacy strings", why does its use here seem so cumbersome? Am I misusing it? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using `std::strings` and calling `c_str()` at the call site, or provide a wrapper for the C function that takes `std::string`'s and forwards the `c_str()` inside?

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently, but the entire purpose of `string_span` and friends is to avoid copies when all you need is a non-owning view into a string. See http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rstr-view and the related Core Guidelines advice on string handling.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. it also seems odd that a literal (which is guaranteed to be null-terminated) isn't implicitly convertible to a `zstring_span`

A string literal is of type `const char[...]`. There is no information in the type that this `const char` array is a null terminated string. Here is some other code with the same types, but without null termination where `ensure_z` will fail fast.

```
const char foo_arr[4]{ 'o', 'd', 'd', '-' };
ensure_z(foo_arr);
```

Both `"foo"` and `foo_arr` are of type `const char[4]`, but only the string literal is null terminated while `foo_arr` is not.

Please note that your combination of `ensure_z` and `czstring_span<>` compiles, but it does not work. `ensure_z` returns only the string without the terminating null byte. When you pass that to the `czstring_span<>` constructor, then the constructor will fail searching for the null byte (which was cut off by `ensure_z`).

You need to convert the string literal to a span and pass that to the constructor:

```
czstring_span<> foo = ensure_span("odd");
```

> 2. There's a similar oddity with `std::string`, which is implicitly convertible to `string_span`, but not `zstring_span`

Good point. There is a constructor for `string_span` that takes a `std::string`, but for `zstring_span` there is only a constructor taking the internal implementation type, a `span<char>`. For `span` there is a constructor taking a "container" having `.data()` and `.size()` - which `std::string` implements.  Even worse: the following code compiles but will not work:

```
zstring_span<> to_zspan(std::string& s) { return zstring_span<>{s}; }
```

You should consider filing an issue in the GSL repo to get the classes aligned. I am not sure if the implicit conversions are a good idea, so I prefer how it is done in `zstring_span` over how `string_span` does it.

> 3. There seems to be some const-correctness issues.

Also here my first idea of `czstring_span<> to_czspan(const std::string& s) { return czstring_span<>{s}; }` compiles but does not work. Another solution would be a new function `ensure_cz` that returns a `span<const char, ...>`. You should consider filing an issue.

> 4. `assume_z()`

The existance of `empty()` and the code in `as_string_span()` suggest that the class was meant to be able to handle empty string spans. In that case `as_string_span` would always return the string without terminating null byte, `ensure_z` would return the string with terminating null byte, failing if empty, and `assume_z` would assume that `!empty()` and return the string with terminating null byte.

But the one and only constructor is taking a non-empty span of characters, so `empty()` can never be `true`. I just created a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/pull/850) to address these inconsistencies. Please consider filing an issue if you think that more should be changed.

> If `zstring_span` is designed "to convert zero-terminated spans to legacy strings", why does its use here seem so cumbersome? Am I misusing it? Is there something I'm overlooking?

In pure C++ code I prefer `std::string_view`, `zstring_span` is only for C interop, that limits its use. And of course you must know the guidelines and the guideline support library. Given that I bet that `zstring_span` is rarely been used and that you are one of the very few people taking a deep look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It's "cumbersome" in part because it's intended to be.

This:

```
zstring_span<> to_zspan(std::string& s) { return ensure_z(s); }
```

Is *not* a safe operation. Why? Because while it is true that `s` is NUL terminated, it is entirely possible that the actual `s` contains internal NUL characters. That's a legitimate thing you can do with `std::string`, but `zstring_span` and whomever takes it can't handle that. They'll truncate the string.

By contrast, `string_span/view` conversions are safe from this perspective. Consumers of such strings take a sized string and thus can handle embedded NULs.

Because the `zstring_span` conversion is unsafe, there should be some *explicit* notation that something potentially unsafe is being done. `ensure_z` represents that explicit notation.

Another problem is that C++ has no mechanism to tell the difference between a literal string argument and any old `const char*` or `const char[]` parameter. Since a bare `const char*` may or may not be a string literal, you have to assume that it isn't and therefore use a more verbose conversion.

Also, C++ string literals can contain embedded NUL characters, so the above reasoning applies.

The `const` issue seems like a code bug, and you should probably file it as such.

Comment: This seems to be more of a semantic issue than one of safety. A similar argument could be made against using `str.c_str()`.

Comment: @johv: Nobody is saying that you *can't* use it. Only that the conversions should be *explicit*. Converting a `std::string` to a `char const*` is always explicit; in this case, you can clearly see a call to `c_str` in the code. Making a `zstring_span` not implicitly convertible from a `std::string` means that you have to explicitly convert it.

Comment: It seem perfectly reasonable to me that the `zstring_span` could contain NULs, just like `std::string` can. I'd expect a NUL-containing `zstring_span` to behave just like a `str.c_str()`, which is safe (there is at least one NUL) to pass to C-functions, which would stop processing the string at the first NUL.

Simply put, one cannot assume that `str.length() == strlen(str.c_str())`, and I would assume the same is true for `zstring_span`.

Comment: @johv: You seem to be off the subject of the topic. This question is about *implicit conversions*. `std::string` is not implicitly convertible to a `char const*` because that conversion is lossy. You lose information *precisely because* `str.length()` and `strlen(str.c_str())` may not be equal. If a conversion potentially loses information, then the conversion ought not be implicit. And that's ***all this answer is speaking to***. Explicit conversions like `c_str` or `ensure_z` are explicit and therefore OK.